# problem slowing down rotation of object rotating around another object in Godot 3

Tags: rotation, godot, pi

I have a simple scene of 2 boxes . box A is static and box B rotates around box A . simple stuff . So I get box B to rotate 180 degrees around box A , however, its rotating too fast . how does one slow the speed down? . i tried to cahnge the rotation limit values  as well as dtheta but it still persists. Can anyone help ? here is the script :

```
var rotation_origin
export var r = 1
var transition_point = Vector3.ZERO
var theta 
var dtheta = 2 * PI / 250
var rotationLimit = PI / 6.5
var boxA 
var boxB
var stopping_distance = 1.0
var velocity = Vector3.ZERO
var move_speed = 2.0
var blend_timer = 0.0
var blend_duration = 7.0  # Adjust the duration of the blend


var state = states.IDLE

enum states {
    IDLE
    SEEK
    ROTATE
}

func _ready():
    boxA = get_node("../boxA")
    boxB = get_node("../boxB")
    
func _process(delta):
    rotateAround(delta)

func rotateAround(delta):
    match state:
        states.IDLE:
            var direction_to_player = get_node("../boxA").global_transform.origin - global_transform.origin
            var distance_to_player = direction_to_player.length()
            if distance_to_player < stopping_distance:
                velocity = Vector3.ZERO
            else:
                state = states.SEEK
        
        states.SEEK:
            var direction_to_player = boxA.global_transform.origin - global_transform.origin
            var distance_to_player = direction_to_player.length()
            direction_to_player = direction_to_player.normalized()
            
            if distance_to_player > stopping_distance:
                velocity = direction_to_player * move_speed
                move_and_slide(velocity)
            elif distance_to_player < stopping_distance:
                state = states.ROTATE
                theta = Vector3(0, 0, 1).angle_to(boxB.global_transform.origin - global_transform.origin)
                rotationLimit 
        
        states.ROTATE:
            # In ROTATE state 
            rotation_origin = boxB.global_transform.origin - boxA.global_transform.origin
            theta += dtheta

            if theta <= rotationLimit:
                var cosTheta = cos(theta)
                var sinTheta = sin(theta)
                var rotated_offset = Vector2(cosTheta * rotation_origin.x - sinTheta * rotation_origin.z,
                sinTheta * rotation_origin.x + cosTheta * rotation_origin.z)

                boxB.transform.origin = boxA.global_transform.origin + Vector3(rotated_offset.x, 0, rotated_offset.y)
                


                
                #boxB.transform.origin.x = boxA.global_transform.origin.x + r * cosTheta
                #boxB.transform.origin.z = boxA.global_transform.origin.z + r * sinTheta
                #boxB.transform.origin.y = boxA.global_transform.origin.y
            else:
                theta = rotationLimit  # Stop the rotation at the limit
                state = states.IDLE
```

Comment: `delta` is the amount of time between frame, I don't see you using it. So you are defining the rotating in angle per frame, not per second. I'd recommend to use delta, and have the rotations per second (which you convert to angle per second very easily), then you would have a more intuitive sense of what rotation speed you are setting.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to answer my query. Unfortunately, my maths isn't my strongest forte but you've filled in a missing piece to the puzzle and I will eventually find the solution. thanks again